# I can verify solutions to my problem in polynomial time, how would a non-deterministic algorithm arrive to a solution if it always takes $2^n$ bits?

Tags: complexity-theory, np

Decision Problem: Given integers as inputs for $K$ and $M$. Is the sum of $2^k$ + $M$ a $prime$?

### Verifier

```
m = int(input('Enter integer for M: '))
sum_of_2**K+M=int(input('enter the sum of 2^k+m: '))

if AKS.sum_of_2**K+M == True:

  # Powers of 2 can be verified in O(N) time
  # make sure there is all 0-bits after the 1st ONE-bit
  
  # Use difference to verify problem

  if sum_of_2**K+M - (M) is a power_of_2:
    OUTPUT Solution Verified
```

*The powers of 2 have approximately $2^n$ digits. Consider $2^k$ where $K$ = 100000. Compare the amount of digits in $K$ to the amount of digits in it's solution!* Also take note that the *powers of 2* have $2^n$ bits as its *0-bit Unary* essentially for the exponent $n$.

### Question

How would a non-deterministic machine solve this problem in polynomial time?

Comment: The complexity of AKS is $$O(log(N)^6)$$ where N is the input number. In your case the complexity would be $$O(K^6)$$. Try editing the post and explain “what exactly is the input to the problem?”.  As for you question about NTM, in general, if you already have polynomial verifier without any witness or certificate, then the verifier is actually the deterministic algorithm. Hence, the same algo will work for NTM.

Comment: I think that the point of the asker is that the number $k$ in the input is encoded as binary, and thus representing the number $2^k + M$ requires an exponential number of bits compared to the size of the input.

Comment: @TravisWells, didn't you post s very similar question to this recently? What happened to that question?

Comment: @prime_hit How would an NTM arrive at the answer that has 2^n bits in polytime? When the only inputs are $K$ and $M$?

Comment: @TravisWells It depends if the input $K$ is in binary or unary. If it is in unary, then this is definitely solvable in polynomial time. $2^K$ requires $K$ bits and AKS can decide the primality of $2^K$ in $O(K^6)$ time. If $K$ is in binary, then I don’t think we can do this in polytime w.r.t this form of input. Note that complexity class depends on the format of input.

Comment: @prime_hit I did notice that some inputs can run in polynomial time if $M$ is > $2^K$ in bit-length. Seems like "evidence" that $NP$!=$EXP$ (correct me, if I come off as strange. I am just an amateur)

Comment: @TravisWells I didn’t quite get you here, but to prove $NP \ne EXP$ you need to come up with a problem which is in $EXP$ but not in $NP$. The number of instances in this problem has to be infinite, because any finite number of instances being “hard” doesn’t make sense. For example, if you give me a very hard sudoku problem claiming “this instance requires exponential time to solve”, I can always hardcode this inputs and give you a linear time algorithm for solving that instance. Same goes for any finite number of instance.

Comment: @prime_hit I apologize for not clarifying the Second sentence. I see it as evidence because $2^k$ requires $2^n$ bits to calculate. Anyway, there is an infinite amount of $M$ inputs that are exponentially smaller than $2^k$. There are an infinite amount of inputs in binary for both $K$ and $M$. The issue is how do we prove that there is NOT an algorithm that can give a yes or no answer in polytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verifier is polynomial in K and M. It’s even polynomial in K and the size of M. But that’s not what we count as “in P”. It would have to be polynomial in the size of K and the size of M. If K = 100,000 then the size of K is just 17 bits. It is highly unlikely that any algorithm can check primality in polynomial time in this number - not even if M=-1 where we have a much faster polynomial in K algorithm.

It’s not proven to be impossible but very very unlikely. Even if I gave you a 50,000 bit divisor of your 100,000 bit number, you couldn’t verify that quickly enough.

Comment: Yes, the verifier is polynomial. But the decision problem requires calculating 2^k. Which takes $2^n$ time. How would an $NP$ machine will "know" a yes or no instance? To circumvent the hassle of using 2^n time?

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, this decision problem is obviously in P. Therefore, there is nothing for non-deterministic Turing machine to guess. Non-deterministic Turing machine would call polynomial-time verifier for a given problem instance and the problem would be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: How? It takes $2^n$ space to store the bits. The verifier would require input with $2^n$ bits no matter what. The Turing machine (non-deterministic) is taking $K$ and $M$ as inputs.

Comment: It seems that I misunderstood. In that case, the problem does not admit polynomial-time verifier and NDTM cannot solve it in polynomial time.

Comment: Its more than that because the problem is already known in to be in $EXP$. It has not been proven that no NP (polynomial) algorithim exists. Perhaps there is a clever way to get "yes" or "no".